# How to increase request timeout in IIS7.0 by php script

Tags: php, settimeout, execution

How to increase script execution time. I have already use this function in my script.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit (10800);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10800);
ini_set('max_input_time', 10800);
ini_set('max_input_nesting_level', 10800);
ini_set('max_input_vars', 10800);
```

I have not server access for change anything and For your information my PHP script Running without safe mode. So what I do for increase script execution time. Any suggestion for me...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I do have access to the server but to programatically change the IIS timeout via a script would be incredibly useful to me. I'll offer my rep for a bounty if not.